# Delete part of a sentence

Tags: regex, r

I have downloaded a database and I would like to clean it. I want to select a part of a sentence which isn't necessary, to delete it and then delete duplicates.

For example :

I have this :

```
10 choco barres
100% pur jus Ananas
100% Pur jus d'orange avec pulpe
100% Pur jus d'orange avec pulpe
```

And I would like this :

```
choco barres
pur jus Ananas
Pur jus d'orange avec pulpe
```

Could someone help me ?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, or an algorithm service!

Comment: What is the actual rule you want implemented? Your one example leads me to believe you want to remove all numbers and percent symbols, but is it only whole numbers? Should 93.2 be removed? And what about other punctuation like ">10"?

Comment: Sorry, I thought SO was a forum to help people.
I want to find a way with gsub, to delete everything as number (100% , 10, (35) ...) and just keep the name of the article. 
Usually, there is a space between the name of the article and the number. So I want to delette everything before the space.
Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: maybe with stri_extract, it would be easier ?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] so people understand what you have tried. It is apparent that you are interested in using `gsub` which the below answer probably gets the most close to what you have described, but even then it is hard to say that answer is 100% correct. Show us what you have tried and what you're missing. Then SO is able to help because we aren't doing your research for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly the things you want to remove can look like, but you're on the right track with `gsub`. If your string is `s`, all you need is something like

```
gsub('[0-9% ]{2,}', ' ', s)
```

which evaluates to

```
[1] " choco barres pur jus Ananas Pur jus d'orange avec pulpe Pur jus d'orange avec pulpe"
```

where `[ ... ]` defines a set of characters to look for and `{2,}` specifies to look for 2 or more of them.

There are a lot of alternatives here, depending on what you need. Spaces in particular can be handled differently.

To get rid of duplicates as well, it's easier to split the string, search for unique strings, and paste it back together:

```
paste(unique(strsplit(s, '[0-9% ]{2,}')[[1]]), collapse = ' ')
```

which returns

```
[1] " choco barres pur jus Ananas Pur jus d'orange avec pulpe"
```

Note that this is dependent on having a numeric string at the beginning of each string segment, and is thus less flexible than the `gsub` approach above.

Check out [the resources on the [regex] tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), which should help you figure out what is necessary.